# What are the best practices for authorization of REST API with federated security?

Tags: rest, authorization, openid-connect, federated-identity

With federated security (e.g. OIDC + external identity provider) the owner of the REST API has no control over the user profile, so the owner of the API cannot store any application-specific information (such as user role or claim) in the user profile.
That means that on each request the REST API has to retrieve the application-specific user profile with the application-specific user role.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You can use an API gateway coupled with an ABAC authorization engine (e.g. Axiomatics) to do exactly what you are looking for. It decouples authorization from the API's logic.

Comment: An API gateway just moves the problem from the API to the gateway. The gateway still needs to retrieve the application-specific user profile on each request.

Comment: No, the authZ engine would and that's what they're designed to do

Comment: The authZ engine still needs to retrieve the application-specific user profile on each request. No magic.

Comment: Yes true but they are designed to do that